Caching images fetched from API in the Svelte build folder using static adapter
I typically use 11ty as a static site generator, but I'm trying out Svelte for more interactivity on a site I'm developing now. I'm using Strapi as a CMS in a logic that I've used with 11ty before: fetching and caching Strapi's API calls (mainly images) in order to obtain, in the end, a static folder of the site with all the files with html links done correctly.
The idea is to use the CMS just to help me fill out the site (it's a portfolio site). I don't want to leave Strapi running all the time to display the images.
How could I do this with Svelte + Sveltekit?
I tried Svelte's static adapter (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) but it doesn't seem to work in this case. The same happens with Svelte's Enhanced Image plugin (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/images), as it only processes images that are in the project folder.
I'm wondering if there is a plugin or some workaround to handle this because I really want to use Svelte for this project.

Any particular reason you want to use Strapi? I use adapter-static for one of my websites, and instead of using a headless CMS such as Strapi, I simply store "entries" as objects in a JS array in a file. And if the entries needs images, I simply put them in the project folder. Quite easy and convenient IMO.

I started with the same logic too, simplifying and using json to store the data and image urls. But the project in question is a book portfolio and I'm using a component I made specifically to render book mockups. The Strapi interface is a great option for viewing book pages and placing them in the order I want them to appear on the page.
